# Do the ancient Japanese healing methods really work?

Tags: realism, ninja-assassin

Do the ancient Japanese healing methods that Raizo performs on himself in the movie Ninja Assassin really work?

Comment: From time to time, a traditional healing practice is found that "really works" in the sense of modern medicine.  But generally it is thought that *most* of them do not.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. In the same way a placebo really work.

It's all about belief. If you believe you're receiving ancient healing, then yes it will probably work in the same way that a vitamin pill works for chronic pain or depression if your doctor convinces you that you're receiving cutting edge medication.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placebo

Answer (score 0):

There are actual documented accounts of people who have been able to impale *themselves* and remove the impaling item without injury. I don't know of any who have been able to heal sword wounds got in battle inflicted by others.

If I knew of an actual ninja ability like this, I would hesitate to reveal it, out of due respectful fear... :-)